# Logrotate errors

Tags: centos6, logrotate

After last update of Centos 6 logrotate is not working correctly.
Anyone can point me to the source of problem?

I've got mails like this:

```
/etc/cron.daily/logrotate:
logrotate_script: line 1: daily: command not found
logrotate_script: line 2: rotate: command not found
logrotate_script: line 3: delaycompress: command not found`
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you possibly putting those lines inside of a script block in your logrotate.conf script or scripts?

For example, inside a "postrotate", "prerotate", "firstaction", "lastaction" block before the "endscript" directive?

That would cause the script to treat those logrotate directives as commands in a script; since they are not commands, you'd get exactly the messages you mentioned.

Comment: Nope, it's not that case. Thank you for trying

Comment: True, after the line with word **postrotate** should be only console commands with einding word **endscript** in a new line.